# Moderator edits of user posts

Tags: discussion, editing, moderators

Granted, I'm new to the RPG section, but I'm a long-time member of Stack Exchange. Don't want to cause a fuss, just want to understand the ground rules.

I'm a little surprised that my opening post was edited by a mod. I've seen posts moved or held for a request to edit, but never a direct edit of my words. (and, frankly, it's a judgement call, not an error or falsehood.) That is unusual in my experience here.

[What does "+1 forward" mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136138/what-does-1-forward-mean)

('long-winded' was altered to 'short-hand')

My use of terms may not be the preferred terminology, but is that cause for altering it without my knowledge or permission? That's literally putting words in my mouth.

Granted, in retrospect, I might have changed it myself - if my attention were drawn to it, but do I now have to periodically revisit all my posts to see if someone has changed what I said to something not what I said?

(Also, not sure if I need to post *this* question here publicly, or if there is a place for asking about edits in the 'edits' section.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edits happen frequently at RPG.SE without the necessity of asking permission or notifying the author. These edits should happen if clarity can be improved. In fact, **the edit you're citing wasn't by a moderator (moderators have a diamond next to their username to identify them), just a regular concerned user**. All users with edit permissions can engage in this communal improvement.

In this particular example, it's fairly clear what you meant, but "a long-winded way of saying" is (ironically) a wordier, less effective, more idiomatic, and possibly disparaging way of saying "a shorthand for saying." Your question will now be easier to read by non-native English speakers, more succinct, and free of possibly negative connotations that you probably didn't intend.

In the event that such an edit really does wreck your intent, you can rollback the edit or edit again, leaving an appropriate revision message to explain why you did so so that it doesn't happen again. However, don't expect your posts to be treated as if they are inviolable. Edits for improvement will happen on occasion, even in ways that you don't consider to be improvements. If it's that important to you then, yes, you'll have to revisit every post you make in perpetuity to see if they've been edited, in which case you won't enjoy RPG.SE's culture.

In this particular example, it looks like you prefer the word "obscure" retroactively. So, by all means, go edit that in. It's really, really unlikely somebody's going to get into an edit war with you on your own post, since that violates the intent of RPG.SE's conventions for communally improving content.

Basically, this is the system at RPG.SE working as intended: the edit called to your attention the fact that your wording could use improvement. Whether you stick with the improvement another user left or go with your own improvement, either way the post will have been improved.

Comment: Thanks. I sometimes forget that SE is more of a Q&A than a discussion place. Answers are geared to be useful to *readers*, not to discussions and opinions and the like. On reflection I was actually considering deleting *this* meta-post as unnecessary.

Comment: You're right: the goal is to be useful to everyone, not just the original poster. Actually, for that reason, it's best to _not_ delete the meta post, because this meta post itself can be illustrative to others about RPG.SE's edit culture.

Comment: @DaveC426913 Your question will be useful to other users; quite a few people react similarly when a question or answer is edited.  Some react very strongly.  We recently had a user react very badly to having an answer edited on Christianity.SE.  The mods had to get involved

Comment: Probably would help to mention that edits made by other users are notified to the user who created the post - there is no need to go back and check in case changes have been made without their knowing.

Comment: @Nij I'm unaware of that, so perhaps you should post an answer about it.

Answer (score 5):

If a post you created receives an edit (of at least ten characters text or two characters code) from another user, this edit will be notified to your inbox, just as if a user has commented or replied to you in chat.

There is no need to go back through all your posts and check for this. If it was edited, you get notified.

*Examples to follow*

Comment: Yeah. I see that now.

Comment: Actually this is only true for "[nontrivial edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135411/323179)", where at least 10 characters are changed.